# How can I add one single tick mark number on the y axis in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to add the number `1.3` to the `y axis`.

Currently, I have:

```
p <- ggplot(data, aes(x = MO, y = value)) + geom_smooth(aes(x=MO, y=value)) +
  geom_line(aes(colour=variable, group=variable), size=2) +
  labs(x = "Model Order", y = "-Log(P-Value)", title = "Granger Causality") + ylim(-2,10) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 1.3, col='green')
p + theme(legend.position = c(0.1, .85))
```

Comment: `p + scale_y_continuous(breaks = 1.3)`

Comment: Thanks it, worked but took away the numbering on the axis, so I just did this:p + scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0, 1.3, 5, 10))